# How to check the installed version of Flutter?

Tags: dart, version, flutter

How do I find the version of Flutter I have installed on my computer?

Comment: use `flutter doctor` command

Answer (score 267, accepted):

use the following command

```
flutter --version
```

Answer (score 64):

### Flutter

- **Version:**

  ```
  flutter --version
  ```
- **SDK location:**

  ```
  where flutter
  ```
- **Detailed information:**

  ```
  flutter doctor -v
  ```
- **Upgrade**

  ```
  flutter upgrade
  ```

- **Change channel** to, say `beta`

  ```
  flutter channel beta
  flutter upgrade
  ```

---

### Dart

- **Version:**

  ```dart
  dart --version
  ```
- **SDK location:**

  ```
  where dart
  ```

Comment: "where dart" doesn't work for me. Getting "bash: where: command not found
"

Comment: Very old, but under bash i believe it is `which dart` @KrishnaShetty

Answer (score 19):

As others have said use

```
flutter doctor
```

or

```
flutter --version
```

If that is not working you need to make sure that the `flutter/bin` directory is in your path:

```
echo $PATH
```

If it isn't see [this link](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path) to add it.

Answer (score 7):

Simply navigate to flutter sdk folder and open the file `version`

```
flutter/version
```

Answer (score 5):

### Flutter

Open the terminal, simply write

```
flutter --version
```

To see full overview and related other necessary things

```
flutter doctor
```

To see the installation path

```
echo $PATH
```

### Dart

To see the dart language version

```
dart --version
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check your flutter version:

```
flutter --version
```

If you want to upgrade the flutter version:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

To know your Flutter SDK version, execute the command below:
flutter --version

SDK location:
where flutter

Detailed information:
flutter doctor -v

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal, navigate to Flutter directory,
run `flutter --version`.

> This command will display the version of Flutter along with other relevant information such as the Dart version and the Flutter channel you're currently using.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).